# Show HTML for specific div on click

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have some HTML and Ajax set up so that if you click a certain image (the `reply-quote` class below), it initiates some Ajax to echo HTML elsewhere on the page.

As shown below, the HTML file contains the same block of divs multiple times. My problem is that, if a user clicks the image, how can I make Ajax show the HTML (within `show-reply` div) for that specific block and not all of them?

```
<!-- BLOCK ONE -->
<div class="style1">
  <div class="style2">
    <img src="image.png" class="reply-quote" />
      <div class="style3">
        <div class="style4">
          <div id="show-reply"></div>
          <div class="reply-box">
            <form class="reply-container no-margin" method="POST" action="">
              <textarea class="reply-field" name="new_comment" placeholder="Write a reply..."></textarea>
              <button name="submit" class="btn" type="submit">Post</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>

<!-- BLOCK TWO -->
<div class="style1">
  <div class="style2">
    <img src="image.png" class="reply-quote" />
      <div class="style3">
        <div class="style4">
          <div id="show-reply"></div>
          <div class="reply-box">
            <form class="reply-container no-margin" method="POST" action="">
              <textarea class="reply-field" name="new_comment" placeholder="Write a reply..."></textarea>
              <button name="submit" class="btn" type="submit">Post</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Here's the JQuery I have right now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $(".reply-quote").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'assets/misc/show_reply.php', // this file simply echoes back the HTML to the `show-reply` div
      type: "POST",
      data: {post_id: $(this).attr('id')},
      success: function(data) {
        $("#show-reply").append(data); // this is where the problem lies
      }
    });
  });
});
```

To my understanding, I have to somehow implement `$(this), parent(), find(), etc.` instead of the current line I'm using (`$("#show-reply").append(data);`). The question is, what should that line be so that if I click the image, it only shows the HTML for that specific block?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: ID should be unique in a document, use class attribute instead for `show-reply` and other elements where `id` is repeated

```
<div class="show-reply"></div>
```

then you need to find the `show-reply` next to the clicked `reply-quote` image

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

    $(".reply-quote").click(function() {
        var $reply = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'assets/misc/show_reply.php', // this file simply echoes back the HTML to the `show-reply` div
            type: "POST",
            data: {post_id: $(this).attr('id')},
            success: function(data) {
                $reply.closest('.comment-container').find(".show-reply").append(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @John there was a bug which I fixed now `$reply.next().find(".show-reply")`

Comment: Won't this cause undefined behavior? Since ajax is async there is no guarantee that `$reply` will still be the same value once you get to the success block.

Comment: @Jordan no it won't as `$reply` is a closure variable its value will not change by another click execution

Comment: @John then the question is whether the ajax request is successfull... add an alert statement in the success handler and see whether it is getting called

Comment: @John did you change the `id` to `class`

Comment: Yes, I have changed it.

Comment: Right now, if I click the image, it will echo the HTML needed, except it echoes it for both blocks, instead of the one I just clicked. I've tried all your suggestions, but that completely stopped it from showing anything.

Comment: @John then it must be some problem with the html... will you be able to try some more stuff

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm here.

Comment: can you check you browser console to see whether there is any error

Comment: Add some more statements to the success handler and check the console `            success: function (data) {
                console.log($reply)
                console.log($reply.next())
                console.log($reply.next().find(".show-reply"))
                $reply.next().find(".show-reply").append(data); // this is where the problem lies
            }`

Comment: What should I be looking for in the console? Anything specific?

Comment: what is logged there?

Comment: a lot of text, too much to enter here

Comment: @John in that case `success: function (data) {
    console.log('reply', $reply);
    console.log('next', $reply.next());
    console.log('show', $reply.next().find(".show-reply"));
    $reply.next().find(".show-reply").append('default text');
    $reply.next().find(".show-reply").append(data);
}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36825/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-john)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $("div").click(function(e) {
            if($(e.target).is('.reply-quote')){
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            alert("work ");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the id="show-reply" to class="show-reply" in html, and then in JS change $("#show-reply").append(data); to $(this).parent(".show-reply").append(data);